# Splitting txt file delimited by tabs into multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently am trying to read an input file that looks like this:

```
annie   Tuesday October 7 at 08:32 pm   1   Cappuccino  2.5
```

It is delimited by tabs. I am trying to read from this file, called orders.txt, and place this is an associative array $array. This is the code I have so far. I have tried several different versions, but no dice.

```
function read_file() {
        $file = "orders.txt";
        $array = array();
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            $myfile = fopen($file, "r");
            $data = file_get_contents($file);
            $lines = explode("\n", $data);
            foreach($lines as $line) {
                $splode = explode("\t", $line);
                $array[] = array(
                    "Name" => $splode[0],
                    "Time" => $splode[1],
                    "Quant" => $splode[2],
                    "Type" => $splode[3],
                    "Price" => $splode[4],
                    );
            }
            fclose($myfile);
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

Could anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Why not try [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Comment: I'd really like to use explode. Is there a way to do this, or is fgetcsv way easier?

Comment: Explode at New line break for an array of the lines. Then pass it to a function to create a multi dimensional array using explode at tab space

Comment: I would like to keep it in the same function if at all possible. I tried something else (which I updated) but it returns errors like:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in vieworders.php on line 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good.  I did add one if statement to make sure splode was 5 long before assigning it.  This is protection against a possible blank line at the end of a file.

I ran it on a test file here with a few lines and it processed correctly and outputted as expected.

Depending on how you're creating this file - could you have a '\r' or a '\r\n' on the end of each line instead of just a \n??  This is something you'd need to check - maybe a hex editor, but I still think your code should run ok (unless it's just a \r) as long as there's enough tabs to satisfy the 5 on each line (which I conditionaled for in my suggestion).

```
function read_file()
{
    $file = "orders.txt";
    $array = array();

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        echo "Get";
        $myfile = fopen($file, "r");
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        $lines = explode("\n", $data);
        var_dump($lines);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $splode = explode("\t", $line);
            if (sizeof($splode) >= 5) $array[] = array(
                    "Name" => $splode[0],
                    "Time" => $splode[1],
                    "Quant" => $splode[2],
                    "Type" => $splode[3],
                    "Price" => $splode[4],
                    );
        }
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    return $array;
}
```